# Update the data source while test execution in Jmeter and then reuse it in the same run

Tags: jmeter

I have the scenario in the JMeter. That scenario uses CSV file with numbers to make the specific POST request.

For example

```
Post /items/new
{
    "id": "number from CSV"   
     
}
```

After that execution in the response, I'm getting a new number.

Let's close eyes on CSV or DB as I thought to sue  - the topic name "Update the data source while test execution in JMeter and then reuse it in the same run". The idea is do not stop the test when datastore became invalid and do not write the separate file.

The test is starting with valid datastore (numeric ids are placed in that) after some POST requests we have to replace id "1" (used to send that POST) from data source on id "2" (we got in the response) and keep "2" in the same test run. When we have a new test cycle (from the same run - we are not stopping the test) we are taking  id "2" to make a new POST and  then we need to replace used "2" on "3" (we got from the response).. and move on. Any ideas how to organize that flow? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save this "new number" from the response into a separate CSV file for later re-use, you can do it as follows:

1. Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to fetch the `id` from the response
2. Use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property so JMeter would write it to the .jtl results file as the last column
3. If you prefer JMeter to write it to the separate CSV file instead - go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear.. I do not want to save this "new number" from the response into a separate CSV file for later re-use.  For example I have 10 records in CSV, I need to repeat the test 20 times for 1 thread. After 10 times the test will be failed since the data became invalid. I've thought that we can use some db for that instead of CSV.. Any ideas?

Comment: I fail to see how DB will solve you issue, if you want to use data only once - set "Recycle on EOF" to "False" and "Stop thread on EOF" to true, then JMeter will stop when the last value will be used.

Comment: Thanks. The idea is do not stop the test when datastore became invalid and do not write the separate file. I've updated the main question, can you take a look please?